# Rendering Django 1.6 RegexField invalid message_error

Tags: python, django

I have a username form field as follows:

```
username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w]+$', max_length=15,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Username')}),
                            label=_('Username'),
                            error_message={'invalid':unicode(_('The given username may only contain letters, numbers and underscores.'))},
                            help_text=_('May only contain the charchters A-Z, a-z and _ max 15 characters.'))
```

When the field is invalid the error that is rendered in the browser is as follows:

```
{'invalid': u'`The given username may only contain letters, numbers and underscores.`'}
```

Is this an issue with crispy-forms or are additional steps that need to be taken to simple return:

```
The given username may only contain letters, numbers and underscores.
```

**Edit:**

this error has nothing to do with crispy forms. Basically I am trying to return the value of the error but the error list is being returned and includes information about the type of error. I get the same value when I run the field in the shell.

Comment: How are you rendering the errors?

Comment: I'm using django-crispy-forms and it does it like this https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/layout/field_errors_block.html

Comment: I solved this using validators https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/
Some changes have been made to the regex field and according to the django source there is a comment that says error_message has be persevered for backwards compatibility but it does seem very compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

username = forms.CharField( max_length=15,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Username')}),
                            label=_('Username'),
                            help_text=_('May only contain the charcters A-Z, a-z and _ max 15 characters.'),
                            validators=[
                                RegexValidator(
                                    regex=r'^[\w]+$',
                                    message=_('The given username may only contain letters, numbers and underscores.'),
                                    code='invalid'),
                            ]
                            )
```

If you open the shell and test what the error is returned you replicate the issue I was facing as seen below.

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w]+$', error_message={'invalid': 'Does not meet requirement'})
>>> username.clean('foo.bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/EJey/Documents/virtualenvs/mysocialenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 150, in clean
self.run_validators(value)
  File "/Users/EJey/Documents/virtualenvs/mysocialenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 139, in run_validators
raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: [u"{'invalid': 'Does not meet requirement'}"]
```

Alternatively use:

```
error_messages
```

as opposed to:

```
error_message
```